# please assist me to add google ads on my website I tried they aren't showing

Tags: html, google-ads-api

I wish to get a guide on how to add google ads on html of my website I tried they are not showing. This is what i have tried so far. I expect that there will come ads but nothing is showing.

**My code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>WEB DEVELOPMENT TUTORIAL</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="logo.jpg">
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="dailyposted.php">DAILY BETTING TIPS</a></li>
                <li><a href="megaposted.php">MEGAJACKPOT PREDICTIONS</a></li>
                <li><a href="midweekposted.php">MIDWEEKJACKPOT PREDICTIONS</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.goal.com">TRANSFER NEWS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="title">
            <h1>SURE DAILY BETTING TIPS</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="button">
            <a href="#" class="btn">WATCH VIDEO</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn">LEARN MORE</a>
        </div>
//I tried to add google auto ads here. The website shows nothing even after 4 hours. please help. Is there any test ads for website please also
        <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
          google_ad_client: "ca-pub-2870870041610409",
          enable_page_level_ads: true
     });
</script>
        </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Why are Google ads not showing up?**

> Google Ads do not show every time a search is performed. ... Even if
>   ads do show, yours may not because someone else paid MORE for their ad
>   to show with the keyword you used. This is where “Pay-Per-Click”
>   bidding is important.
>
> **Reasons Your Google Ads May Not Show:** • The biggest reason: Your AdWords keywords were simply outbid by another person, with their ads
>   showing instead of yours.
>
> • Let’s say you have a cupcake shop. If you are searching a keyword
>   that relates highly to your business like “cupcakes”, your site might
>   just show up “organically”. In this case, Google would not show your
>   ad – instead, they deliver your website as the search result.
>
> • Google Ads do not show every time a search is performed. Only a few
>   ads may show every third search. Even if ads do show, yours may not
>   because someone else paid MORE for their ad to show with the keyword
>   you used. This is where “Pay-Per-Click” bidding is important.
>
> • If you’re shown your ad a few times and don’t click on it, Google
>   thinks you are not interested in the ad and will stop showing it to
>   you. Maybe your ad did show and you just didn’t click it?
>
> • Have you tried looking beyond the first Google search results page?
>   Your ad may be showing on the second Google page, or even the third.
>
> • Your personal IP address used to search the ad may be linked to your
>   AdWords account. Google may not always show your ads to you because
>   you are the creator of them. They want to show the ad to a real
>   searcher who may interact with the ad “organically”. Use the Ad
>   Preview and Diagnosis tool in AdWords to get information about your ad
>   without racking up bad impressions and clicks.
>
> • You may have reached your daily AdWords budget already at the time
>   you searched.
>
> **So, What Can I Do?** • Add a “Call to Action” to each ad. Something like “learn more here”, people will respond.
>
> • Add Ad Extensions, like a link to your contact page, so users only
>   have one click to get there. This increases your ad’s Quality Score
>   and may make it show up more often.
>
> • Pause or remove poorly performing keywords and add new, more
>   relevant ones using the AdWords Keyword Planner. Run all keyword match
>   types for your most relevant keywords and include them in the
>   headlines of your ads.
>
> • Same goes for ads. Rewrite poor performing ads so they are higher
>   quality.
>
> • Use Google Analytics data to see when your customers are online and
>   schedule ads to show at those times. Also, use Bid Adjustments in
>   AdWords to automatically bid higher during peak times.
>
> • Have your ads rotate evenly so that they all have a chance to show
>   to gain a better understanding of which ones work and which do not.
>
> • Bid higher on keywords. Even though Google says this is not
>   necessary, it is a bidding war after all!
>
> In the Google ultraverse, your ads will show if they are high quality,
>   relevant, and you are the highest bid. A combination of these will win
>   you that coveted spot at the top of a Google search results page, and
>   we all like to be in first place sometimes.

https://uptownstudios.net/client-faqs-google-ad-not-showing/